# Related Field got invalid lookup: user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Error.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to `exclude` the users that are my `followers` from the `BlogPost Page`.

I am using `exclude` method to exclude the users.

When i go to the browser then it keep showing :-

> Related Field got invalid lookup: user

models.py

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default=''  )
```

views.py

```
def posts(request,user_id):
    followed_users= request.user.profile.followers.all()

    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=now).exclude(post_owner__user=followed_users)

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'blogpost.html', context)
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your `Post` model?

Comment: Added the `Post` Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `post_owner__user` lookup since `post_owner` is already an aliace to `User` model. Also you can't filter by equality here becase on the right side of the expression you have not a single instance of `User`, but a queryset.
Try this instead:

```
followed_users= request.user.profile.followers.all()
followed_users = list(followed_users.values_list('id', flat=True))
posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=now).exclude(post_owner_id__in=followed_users)
```

First line will return only `User` ID field values that you can use in exclude with [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) expression.

Comment: It now says **'str' object has no attribute 'values_list'**

Comment: I guess you forgot to that first line is `followed_users= request.user.profile.followers.all()` - this is a queryset and `values_list` is the one of it's methods. I updated answer code.

Comment: That's the Thing, Thank You Very Much. It Worked